# How can I handle missing values when fitting IRT model?

Tags: item-response-theory

I am conducting a study for analyzing male involvement in Family planning. It is of interest to develop an index for the involvement of male. I am currently having difficulties fitting an IRT model since my data has a lot of missing values and answers like "don't know" and some confusing answers. Note that my variables are all dichotomous in nature.

Any suggestions for handling this kind of problem regarding missing values in IRT model?Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Item Response Theory is perfect for handling data with missing values.  In classical test theory, scores tend to be summed and subjects not answering questions wind up in their observations being removed.  IRT and Rasch programs are designed to handle missing data.  As the analysis is based on the probability of a subject with a determined ability selecting the response, a missing response just does not contribute to the item measure.

The more blank responses a subject submits, the greater will be the size of the standard error associated with that subject's ability estimate.  Higher missing observations for items will also increase the standard error associated with the difficulty of those items. It is up to the analyst to determine when the standard errors are too high to be useful.

With your dichotomous scoring, correct answers should be scores a 1, incorrect answers a 0, and missing answers as blank (or whatever value the software is programmed to accept for missing).  The missing cells will not contribute to the estimates; that is to say, they will not be scored as a zero.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Just to add to this a bit, if responses like 'don't know' exist in your data, and you believe that these still contribute to your latent trait estimation (say, 'don't know' is sometimes a higher/lower response than 'no') then fitting models like the nominal/nested-logit may be informative to see how the response curves look when including these options (nested-logits still include information about which is most 'correct'). Otherwise, as @doug.numbers suggests, it might be better just to set them as missing and let the IRT software just skip those particular data points.

Comment: thanks to the both of you. but what if the missing data is MNAR(missing not at random) and not MCAR or MAR? SHould I still skip them?Many literature states different techniques like modeling those non-ignorable missing data.What should I do? Well, if my data is MCAR or MAR, should I skip them?thanks

Comment: Do you have any reference related to your answers?thanks

Comment: If your data is MCAR or MAR then keeping them in is fine, otherwise you get into a bit of trouble and have to deal with the missing data mechanism directly. The literature is mixed on what to do when MNAR since improper imputation methods (or other things analytical) can introduce severe bias in your estimates if you choose a poor missing data proxy mechanism. Could you modify your question to describe the reason you believe you have MNAR as well? It will make it more clear what the issue is.

Comment: Thanks, I have confirmed that I have MAR missing data. I understood that it can be kept as missing in fitting IRT models. But what if I'm gonna fit another logistic model which is not IRT. (e.g. ordinal logit model). Should I kept the MAR data as missing and fit the logit model or should I do some imputations?

Comment: That sounds like an entirely different analysis focus, and I don't think there's been enough information provided to answer that. My general inclination is to leave the data as-is unless you can gain a good amount of information by imputation.